# WriteConsole returns false in MASM

Tags: windows, assembly, masm

I am trying to make an array, and access it's values and print them out

After calling the WriteConsole subroutine, it is returning false, however, all the values are supplied. Here we can see that - https://i.stack.imgur.com/bDEpC.jpg
Eax register is 0 after calling WriteConsole. Here you can see the register values, that are being pushed to the stack. https://i.stack.imgur.com/g3g9y.jpg
Considering, that WriteConsole is WINAPI subroutine, that means it's stdcall. So, I am passing values right to left.

```
lpReserved -> 0
lpNumberOfCharsWritten -> offset to 00403028 (CharsWritten variable)
nNumberOfCharsToWrite -> Just 2, because in array only ints are present of length 2
*lpBuffer -> ebx register, which contains array lvalue
hConsoleOutput -> Output from GetStdHandle (In this case -> edx register -> A0)
```

My MASM code:

```
.386
.model flat,stdcall
option casemap:none
include \masm32\include\windows.inc
include \masm32\include\kernel32.inc
includelib \masm32\lib\kernel32.lib
include \masm32\include\user32.inc
include C:\masm32\include\masm32.inc
includelib C:\masm32\lib\masm32.lib
includelib \masm32\lib\user32.lib
includelib \masm32\lib\msvcrt.lib ; Some default includes :P

.data

dArray              dd  10 dup (?)      ; Main array
CharsWritten        dd ?
LoopCounter         dd 0
StdHandle           dd ?
.code


PrintArrayToScreen proc

mov eax, STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE
push eax
call GetStdHandle

mov StdHandle,eax
mov eax,[LoopCounter]
innerPrintLoop:
mov ecx,offset dArray
mov eax, [LoopCounter]
mov ebx,[ecx + eax * 4]
mov esi,offset CharsWritten

push 0
push esi
push 2
push ebx
mov edx,StdHandle
push edx

call WriteConsole

mov eax,[LoopCounter]
inc eax
mov LoopCounter,eax ; Storing the Loop Counter in the variable
cmp eax,11  ; +1 because of loop counter increment
jnz innerPrintLoop
ret
PrintArrayToScreen endp

arrayLoop proc          ; Subroutine for the array filling
mov eax,offset dArray
mov bx,10
mov ecx,0
innerLoop:
mov [eax + ecx * 4],bx  ; ecx * 4 => counter * 4 bytes
inc bx
add ecx,1
cmp ecx,10
jne innerLoop
mov eax,offset dArray
ret
arrayLoop endp

start:
call arrayLoop
call PrintArrayToScreen
mov eax,0
push eax
call ExitProcess
end start
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/writeconsole) for `WriteConsole`:

> *lpBuffer [in]*
>
> A pointer to a buffer that contains characters to be written to the console screen buffer.

So you should be passing the address of the data to be written, but you're actually passing the data itself.

You could "fix" that by changing the line `mov ebx,[ecx + eax * 4]` to `lea ebx,[ecx + eax * 4]`. But note that `WriteConsole` doesn't do any integer-to-string conversion for you, so you still probably wouldn't get the result you expected. If you want that sort of functionality, use `printf`.